# How do I render a variable in a URL path in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following line:

```
var myCustomVariable = '3434';
urlpath = '/people/myCustomVariable/folders/byid/'
```

I want to render the value of myCustomVariable in the urlpath but being new to JS I am unable to figure this out.  I tried doing the following but didn't work:

```
"+myCustomVariable+"!"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: like this you mean `urlpath = '/people/'+ myCustomVariable = '/folders/byid/'`

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `+` operator:

```
var myCustomVariable = '3434';
urlpath = '/people/' + myCustomVariable + '/folders/byid/'
```

This is called "concatenation" or (because we're dealing with strings) "string concatenation."

Your "I tried doing the following..." uses double quotes and a `!`. I'm not sure where the `!` comes from, but in JavaScript, if you open a string with a single quote, you must end it with a single quote; and if you open it with a double quote, you must end it with a double quote.

Comment: I would've just sent the guy to a documentation about concatenation

Comment: @meanIOstack: An example is frequently worth more than all the tutorials in the world. So I go with an example *and* the term to search for. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just do the concatenation of strings like this:

```
var myCustomVariable = '3434';
urlpath = '/people/' + myCustomVariable  + '/folders/byid/'
```

When you do this:

```
"+myCustomVariable+"
```

That represents a string, not your variable. Your variable is

```
myCustomVariable
```

Without the `"` aroud it

See this:

```
var myCustomVariable = '3434';

//This
urlpath = '/people/' + myCustomVariable + '/folders/byid/'
//Same than
urlpath = '/people/' + '3434' + '/folders/byid/'
//Same than
urlpath = '/people/3434/folders/byid/'
```

But

```
var myCustomVariable = '3434';

//This
urlpath = '/people/' + '+myCustomVariable+' + '/folders/byid/'
//Same than
urlpath = '/people/+myCustomVariable+/folders/byid/'
```